# Assigning different links to different images and having it play the assigned (youtube) link on the iframe container

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, video, youtube

So what I want is something whereby;
upon click on "img1", it will display the "video1" at the "video here" area as well as show "text1" on the "text" area.

and upon click of "img2", the same thing will and replaces "text1" with "text2" in the "text" area, and replace "video1" with "video2" in the "video here" area.

Any suggestions? No codes yet as of now. Just kind of wanted to know if anyone had a base idea on how to start this since I am really new to javascript/jquery.

using direct urls to the youtube videos would be best.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First in the image, add the link of the youtube video that you want to play

```
<img src='image' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jQuery('#video-div').attr('src','//www.youtube.com/embed/S-JtVTTMU2A?autoplay=1');jQuery('.video').show();"  />
```

Now create a div to display the video in it.

```
<div class="video">
<iframe id="video-div" width="500" height="500" src=""  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And if you want to change the text, use this code on the click of the img

```
document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML = 'your text';
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope I have got the right idea here but I have written some code that will hopefully help with your question.

Here is my result: http://jsfiddle.net/6m92mkj8/2/

```
<a href="YOUTUBE_URL" title="VIDEO_TITLE"><img src="IMG_URL" alt=""></a>
```

I have kept my code clean and sort of commented for you to understand.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!! It was an immense help. I'm really new to javascript and jquery and your code was so clean I managed to understand it almost immediately. Thank you very much!!

And what are the odds, I'm a huge "Dirty Heads" fan as well. Ahaha.

Comment: Nice one bro, glad to have helped!

Comment: Just another quick question. Where did you get the jQuery src file for this?

Comment: Because it works on jfiddle but not on my html project for some weird reason.